# Get value of object laravel 4

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel, laravel-4

I get the following object data

```
  ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
  ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
  ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
  ["wording"]=> string(1174) "Some Text"  
  ["container"]=> string(8) "training" 

  ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
  ["created_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
  ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
  ["wording"]=> string(1174) "Some Text"  
  ["container"]=> string(8) "relax"
```

Which I get from the DB using

```
 $wording = text_start::all();
```

Now, I want to find where `container = training, container = relax, ...` and echo the appropriate wording accordingly:

```
$training = $wording->contains('training');
$taste = $wording->contains('taste');
$relax = $wording->contains('relax');
$risultati = $wording->contains('risultati');


<span><h2>{{ Str::upper($wording[$relax]->container) }}</h2></span>
<span>{{ Str::limit($wording[$relax]->wording ,400,'...') }}</span>
```

Unfortunatelly, I get the contents of training every time. How could I do this?

Comment: what is `$relax`? What do you mean by you get the contents of training?

Comment: Well, when I echo $wording[$relax]->container it should output relax, but it gives me training all the time

Comment: Posted what you could do. But it won't give you exactly the data structure you need. If you really can't figure how to get it . tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the collection's `keyBy` method:

```php
$wording = text_start::all()->keyBy('container');
```

```html
<span><h2>{{ Str::upper($wording['relax']->container) }}</h2></span>
<span>{{ Str::limit($wording['relax']->wording ,400,'...') }}</span>
```

Comment: I knew laravel has something to offer here... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The contains function is not meant to be used the way you are using it

`contains` returns a boolean value that is specified in the docs.

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_contains

So every time if it contains that key (which it doesn't as training is not a key), it returns true. Hence every time the function returns `false` or `0`. It then picks up the `0th` index which is training

If I understand you correctly you are attempting to use it like a `where`.I would recommend sorting the array you get first and then picking up the appropriate order

```
usort($wording, function($a, $b) {
      return $a['training'] - $b['training'];
});

<span><h2>{{ Str::upper($wording[$relax]->container) }}</h2></span>
<span>{{ Str::limit($wording[$relax]->wording ,400,'...') }}</span>
```

Alternately you could restructure the data itself.

Comment: Thanks, I get it figured out! I thought laravel had any special features for this, too...